# Can such categorical notion of action be formalized?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, sketches

I'm wondering if it's possible to find an universal construction for a general concept of action for (single-sorted?) finite product sketches, such that one of those is "acting" on the second in the usual sense.

Let me explain by giving example:

i) a group action is a group acting on a set (associativity, stabilization by neutral elements),

ii) a vector space is a field acting on a commutative group (associativity, distributivity, stabilization by neutral elements),

iii) a module is a ring acting on a commutative group (associativity, distributivity, stabilization by neutral elements),

iv) an algebra is a field acting on a "pseudo ring" (non associative ring),

degenerated case:
v) a ring is a monoid $M$ biacting on a commutative group $A$, where $M = A$ as objects.

Now, what I would like to do is taking the categories associated to the sketches of a group and a set (say), and produce a new category that is sketching the notion of "action of group on a set". The previous example would become

i) the category associated to the sketch of a group object acting on the terminal category is the sketch of a group object action,

ii) the category associated to the sketch of a field object acting on the category associated to the sketch of a commutative group object is a vector space object,

iii) the ring object acting on the commutative group object is a module object,
etc.

Does anyone has ever heard of such concept? Do you guys think that it could also be formalized for general sketches, thus creating the general notion of "category acting on a category" in the previous sense?

Comment: These are all essentially examples of monoid actions for a monoid in a monoidal category.

Comment: What I want is to take two categories and consider that the resulting action of one category on the other is another category as I said. I don't see how what you say is related to what I want, mind you expliciting?

Comment: It is not as general as you ask for. I am just pointing out that there is something that captures the examples you mention.

Comment: Actually to come up with the correct notion of action is not entirely trivial. There is something called *actor* or *split extension classifier* which gives endomorphisms for monoids, automorphisms for groups, derivations for Lie algebras, bimultiplications for associative algebras, biderivations for Leibniz algebras...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: do you have any references where this concept is introduced? I can't find it easily using google and arxiv. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the best place to start is "[Actors in categories of interest](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702574.pdf)" as it contains sort of brief survey, works in sufficient but not too overwhelming generality, and contains lots of both historical and relatively fresh references

Comment: In few words - if you are in a variety where kernels make sense (so e. g. monoids are ruled out) then you look at retracts $X\rightarrowtail Y\twoheadrightarrow X=1_X$, and find out how $X$ "acts" on the kernel of $Y\twoheadrightarrow X$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I find it weird that they formalize it that way. A monoid set-action is easily defined through the usual concept of map $.: M\times X \rightarrow X$ that is associative and stuff. Moreover, it seems that representation of groups or lie algebra are just actions in the same sense (instead of acting on set, they act on a vector space $V$, $.: G\times V \rightarrow V$). I'll try to think if there exists an universal way using this "sketch" approach. Thanks for the references though.

Comment: Well still there is some variation. For example, just compare a Lie algebra action and an associative algebra action. There must be some intrinsic explanation why the "correct" action is by derivations in the first case but not in the second, right?

Comment: If you refer to the action on itself, I agree. It still seems that given a structure with some operations, and another structure with other operations, it is enough to know the nature of the operations to define the good concept of action. I guess one would have to do some kind of "zoology" of operations (are they associative? considered as additive or multiplicative? distributive?) in order to define such construction and look for a universal way to define them. The concept of action is unifying, so there must be something to understand there.

Comment: There is a standard trick for that too, - actually I mentioned it here [in an answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/157146/41291): internal abelian group $p:A'\to A$ in algebras over an algebra $A$ splits as a semidirect product of $A$ and the kernel of $p$, and can be reconstructed from $A$ and the action on the kernel. The notion of semidirect product and action depends on the variety where the algebra resides. This actually to a certain extent works even for monoids, by calling "kernel" the family of inverse images of elements of $A$ (in better cases determined by each other).