# Name of rule involving elements of two sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology

For sets $X,Y$ and a function $f: X\times Y\to X$, what is the name of the property whereby for all $x\in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y,$ 
$$f(f(x,y_1), y_2) = f(f(x, y_2),y_1)\qquad?$$

Some of us called it a "generalized associativity," some "generalized commutativity," some a combination of both.

Anything we can find on associativity and commutativity and so on assumes the binary relation is inside some $X$.

We used this inside of a proof, but can't find the analogous mathematical concept.

Comment: Mathematicians would write the question thus: if $f:X\times Y\to X$ then what is the name of the property $f(f(x,y_1),y_2)=f(f(x,y_2),y_1)$? If you think of $f$ as giving a right action of $Y$ on $X$, i.e. a map from the set $Y$ to the semigroup of endomorphisms of $X$, then the assertion is just that the image of $Y$ lands in a commutative subsemigroup.

Comment: Said another way, you have a family of endomaps $f_y : X \to X$ parameterized by $y \in Y$, and the desired condition is that these maps commute.

Comment: The two comments above nicely illustrate an peculiarity of notational taste I’ve always found somewhat amusing.  Most mathematicians dislike the curried notation $f : A \to (B \to C)$, and strongly prefer the form $f : (A \times B) \to C$.  But the very same people may be quite happy to say things like “a family of maps $f_a : B \to C$, parametrised by $a \in A$”.  It seems to be some sort of residual aversion to the explicit consideration of higher-order types and functionals.

Comment: Even with some Google assistance I've been unable to decipher the meaning of the second sentence ("PL-group" / "professional reject").

Comment: I'd just call this "associative", or maybe "externally associative" if there's a risk of ambiguity.

Comment: Speaking informally, I'm hard-pressed to see anything associative in this; any way you slice it, it's not simply a 'regrouping' of terms but very clearly involves a reordering of operations among the $y$s. It is much more commutative than associative in flavor (and this can be formalized, of course, as in the answer given).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, personally, I would have no problem with $f:A\to\mathrm{Hom}(B,C)$. My only objection to $f:A\to(B\to C)$ is that I don't think of $B\to C$ as denoting the set of all morphisms from $B$ to $C$. (And I don't think I'm unusual in this respect.)

Answer (score 1):

You could say "$f$ makes $X$ into a *commutative* [$Y$-unary algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21152/do-non-associative-objects-have-a-natural-notion-of-representation/244550#244550)" or that "$f$ is a commutative $Y$-unary algebra structure on $X$."

For instance, defining

$$f : \{N,E\} \times \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^2$$ by $$f(N,(x,y)) = (x+1,y) \qquad f(E,(x,y)) = (x,y+1)$$

we have that $(\mathbb{N}^2,f)$ is the commutative $\{N,E\}$-unary algebra freely generated by $\{(0,0)\}$.