# Notion of module over commutative post lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Let $ (S, \{. \}, [.]) $ be an algebra over a vector
 space endowed with two bilinear maps $ \{. \}, [.] : S \times  S \rightarrow S$ and satisfying some compatibility conditions.

In example, if S is a Poisson algebra; the structure of Poisson module over S is well known

im asking  if there is ( in a abstract way) a general definition of module over $S$ compatible with the two structures $\{. \}, [.] $

Edited; the example i am interested in, is when $S$ is a CPA-algebra ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379519303933)); that is $ (S,  [.]) $ is a Lie algebra and $ (S,.) $  a commutative algebra such that 
$$[x,y].z = x.(y.z) - y.(x.z)$$
$$x.[y,z] = [x.y,z] + [y,x.z]$$

Comment: In some sense, the Poisson module can be better thought of as a Poisson *bi*module because of the antisymmetry of the bracket and symmetry of multiplication. If you accept that, then there is a relatively natural definition: a module $E$ is a vector space (over the same underlying field) such that $S \oplus E$ is the "same kind" of algebra (i.e. it satisfies the same compatibility conditions), where you set $\{e_1, e_2\} = [e_1, e_2] = 0$ for $e_1, e_2 \in E$.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267686/seeing-modules-as-ring-extensions

Comment: is there a reference for this definition; for my situation the category of those modules must be stable under tensor and Hom

Comment: I haven't really worked with the definition, so I can only give you the answers given me; darij grinberg's comment uses Triples, Algebras, and Cohomology (http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/2/tr2.pdf), while another comment gives nLab(https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module#ModulesOverARingInTermsOfStabilizedSlices)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for the notion of a *module over an algebra over an operad*. In your case, the operad is the Poisson operad.

You can find a brief reference in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+an+algebra+over+an+operad). And more details in Loday-Vallette's book "Algebraic Operads"; particularly in section 12.3.1. Even more details in this paper by Berger and Moerdijk: [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.2664.pdf).