# Non-associative module theory

Tags: non-associative-algebras

I'm looking for a reference that treats basic module theory over non-associative rings, the isomorphism theorems and so on. I imagine the theory is known, but have not been able to find a reference.

Edit: Let $R$ be a non-associative ring. By a left $R$-module (similarly for a right $R$-module), I mean an abelian group (M,+) and an operation $\cdot\colon R\times M\to M$, such that for all $r_1,r_2\in R$ and all $m_1,m_2\in M$, the following hold:

1. $(r_1+r_2)\cdot m_1 = r_1\cdot m_1 + r_2\cdot m_1$,
2. $r_1\cdot(m_1+m_2) = r_1\cdot m_1 + r_1\cdot m_2$,
3. $1\cdot m_1 = m_1$ if $R$ is unital.

Comment: You should start with a definition of what a module would be... there's a notion of module over an associative ring, over a Lie ring, but they don't match... in the first case you have the axiom $(ab)x=a(bx)$ and in the second case you have $(ab)x=a(bx)-b(ax)$. If you choose the first axiom, an $A$-module is just a module over the largest associative quotient of $A$...

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking for something on universal algebra?

Comment: As regards the edit, you now seem to want a notion of module which is unrelated to the multiplicative structure of $R$!

Comment: For some sensible versions see the question [Do non-associative objects have a natural notion of representation?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21152/41291) here on MO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do non-associative objects have a natural notion of representation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21152/do-non-associative-objects-have-a-natural-notion-of-representation)

Comment: @YCor: Yes and no. This seems like a natural definition if one later wants the ring to be a module over itself, which I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google search of this term brings a number of references, did you try it?

In any case, a very obvious relevant reference is the old paper of Osborn called [Modules over nonassociative rings](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927877808822293?journalCode=lagb20).

More recent works define modules over any kind of algebras using the language of operads, but I am not sure that this is what you want since you did not indicate your background and the research area you are coming from.

Comment: Believe it or not, I am a frequent user of their service(s). I have seen that reference a couple of times before, but never been able to get hold of the paper. Will try harder, as the title and abstract really seem intriguing.